# remove child tag and concatinate its value to the name of the parent tag

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Is it possible to achieve this with XSLT 1.0 please?

Example input would be

```
<Variable_Attributes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    <Row>
        <MATNR>3006921_CAR</MATNR>
        <REFERENCE>
            <uom>EA</uom>
            <product_id>3006921_EA</product_id>
            <quantity>6</quantity>
        </REFERENCE>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <MATNR>3006921_CAR</MATNR>
        <REFERENCE>
            <uom>CAR</uom>
            <product_id>3006921_EA</product_id>
            <quantity>6</quantity>
        </REFERENCE>
    </Row>
</Variable_Attributes>
```

I would like to remove the `<uom>` tags, and rename the parent `<REFERENCE>` tags by concatenating the value from the deleted uom tag.

So the above would become:

```
<Variable_Attributes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    <Row>
        <MATNR>3006921_CAR</MATNR>
        <REFERENCE_EA>
            <product_id>3006921_EA</product_id>
            <quantity>6</quantity>
        </REFERENCE_EA>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <MATNR>3006921_CAR</MATNR>
        <REFERENCE_CAR>
            <product_id>3006921_EA</product_id>
            <quantity>6</quantity>
        </REFERENCE_CAR>
    </Row>
</Variable_Attributes>
```

Best wishes

Lennon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xsl:element` allows you to compute the name of a result element e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="REFERENCE">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}{uom}">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="uom"/>
```

Of course the base processing will be done by the identity transformation template.